# PrimeNG Calendar custom year range

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I'm trying to redesign PrimeNG Calendar component.

I'd like to make my custom header, and custom year range.

[image]

```html
<p-calendar [formControl]="control">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <div>Custom header</div>
  </ng-template>
</p-calendar>
```

If I use this content projection, I get new header line, but I don't overwrite origin header. I would like to display years in 3 columns. When I overwrite styles, I get 3 columns, but for 3 columns I need 12 years instead of 10. In the documentation there is the decade parameter, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style to your CSS:

```
p-calendar .p-calendar .p-datepicker .p-yearpicker .p-yearpicker-year {
    width: 33.3%;
}
```

If it doesn't work right away, try adding `::ng-deep` at the beginning of the selector:

```
::ng-deep p-calendar .p-calendar .p-datepicker .p-yearpicker .p-yearpicker-year {
```

If it still doesn't work, add `!important`:

```
width: 33.3% !important;
```

This should be the result:

[image]

**Note:** The element structure might differ between different versions of PrimeNG so if it doesn't work, let me know which version you're using. Also, if you update the PrimeNG version, you'll might have to make changes to the CSS.

---

**Edit:** Unfortunately, the number of years that appear in the list is currently hardcoded to be 10. This can be seen in [this file](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts) in the method `yearPickerValues()`:

```
yearPickerValues() {
    let yearPickerValues = [];
    let base = this.currentYear -  (this.currentYear % 10);
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // <-- here
        yearPickerValues.push(base + i);
    }

    return yearPickerValues;
}
```

You can open an issue on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues) and ask them to add an input perhaps.

Comment: Thank you, yes, i tried same thing, but i would like to show 12 years range. For better display years, when i have a 3 columns. And i don't know how i can do that, if it is possible ?

`2020 2021 2022 \n
2023 2024 2025 \n
2026 2027 2028 \n
2029 2030 2031`

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of years in the list is hardcoded to be 10. You can open an issue on their GitHub page if you want them to change it to be an input of the component perhaps. I'll add this detail to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this. I am using `viewChildren`. You can use `viewChild` as well. With this you have to use that instance inside `ngAfterViewInit` hook and perform this operation below

```
@ViewChildren(Calendar) calendarInstances!: QueryList<Calendar>; 


this.calendarInstances.forEach((instance) => {           
   instance.yearPickerValues = function () { 
         let yearPickerValues = []; 
         let base = <number>this.currentYear - (<number>this.currentYear % 12);                  
         for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
           yearPickerValues.push(base + i);                 }                
           return yearPickerValues; 
    }; 
});
```